# Python How to wait for 5 seconds?

Tags: python, sockets, time

I am doing socket programming in Python and sending queries to multiple servers.

I need to wait 5 seconds for a server to respond to that query, if I don't get a response in 5 seconds, Ill send that same query to another server.

How can I start a timer for 5 seconds, when it expires, execute the code on the bottom ? (assuming I don't get a response)

Will sleep(5) work in this situation as if I get a response before 5 seconds, will it still wait 5 seconds ? If that's the case, I don't want to use it.

Comment: `sock.timeout = 5; sock.recv(1000)` something liek that

Comment: Show us the code with the query you are talking about!

Comment: There is a lot to unpack in what you have asked. I think spending time on actually listing the things you need or thinking of how to better phrase the question would be appreciated. Anyway, given your description I gave you an answer of what I think you want...

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do

```
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Could be just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about socket programming is you are free to do whatever you want and there are many things to build a solution for a given problem. That is also the very bad thing about socket programming...

Anyway, given your description I think using [non-blocking sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets) and select loops ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)), [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html)) would do just fine.

Here's a code snippet of how that works using a UDP socket to communicate with your server, would be similar for TCP.

```
<!-- language: «Python» -->
import socket
import select

udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_socket.setblocking(0)

# Optional bind the socket to a local port
udp_socket.bind(('', 6666))

# send your request
....
# wait for an answer AT MOST X seconds
readable, _, _ = select.select([udp_socket], [], [], 5) # X is 5 in this case as you requested

# At this point either 5 seconds would have passed or your socket would have some information (response) in it earlier than the 5 seconds

if readable: # check if socket received a response
    response = readable[0].recv(1024)
```

You can check that it works by faking a server response by sending something to your socket while `select` is waiting. You can do that by sending using /dev/udp.
To do that use:

```
echo "data" > /dev/udp/127.0.0.1/6666
```

Where 6666 in this case is the port the socket is bound to.